# Identifying the parameters of a linear state-space-model using Kalman Filter

Tags: modeling, state-space, kalman-filter

I have a linear state space model (SSM) that looks like this

\begin{align}
    {\dot {x}} & = {\rm \textbf{A}}{x} + {\rm \textbf{B}}{u}                                     \\
    {y}    & = {\rm \textbf{c}}{x} 
\end{align}

I was able to roughly estimate the value of the matrix \$A\$ & \$B\$. While \$C\$ is known! I would like to fine tune the value of the elements of these matrices.

\$\textbf{A}\$ is 4x4, 
 \$\textbf{B}\$ is 3x4, and \$\textbf{C}\$ is 1x4. There are made up from a combination of ten parameters. Can I use the Kalman filter to somehow estimate the value of these parameters? If so, can you please explain to my how I can do it and if I need to redfine my system.

Thinking along the line of Online-parameter estimation. If Kalman Filter cannot be used, can you explain why and what alternatives are there?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question

Comment: The KF estimates the state, and not the A, B, C, D matrices. You need parameter estimation - Matlab has a toolbox to do this, including least squares, instrumental variable

Comment: that is true, however the I have seen some works do the so called -joint state-parameter estimation- with the Kalman filter.